# Managing an array on PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a php script in which I want an output as follow.
I have this code:

```
$query_man = query
$output_man = mysql_query($query_man);

if(mysql_num_rows($output_man) > 0){

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($output_manutenzione)){

    echo "\t" . $row['hostname'];
    echo "\n\t\tTipo Manutenzione: " . $row['type'];
    echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . $row['startdate'];
    echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . $row['enddate'];
    echo "\n\t\tUtente: " . $row['user'];
    echo "\n\t\tMotivo: " . $row['desc'];
    echo "\n\t\tStato: " . $row['State'] . "\n\n";
}
```

where type, startdate, enddate etc. are query fields.

In this way I get an outup like this (e.g.):

```
Hello1
   program
   2016-10-13 09:00
   2016-10-13 10:00
   kevin
   test
   open

Hello1
   program
   2016-10-13 13:00
   2016-10-13 15:30
   john
   test
   closed

Hello2
   program
   2016-10-12 11:00
   2016-10-13 11:30
   susan
   test
   closed

Hello3
   program
   2016-10-12 13:00
   2016-10-12 15:30
   clay
   test2
   open
```

Well, I don't understand how to get the following outup:

```
Hello1
   program
   2016-10-13 09:00
   2016-10-13 10:00
   kevin
   test
   open

   program
   2016-10-13 13:00
   2016-10-13 15:30
   john
   test
   closed

Hello2
   program
   2016-10-12 11:00
   2016-10-13 11:30
   susan
   test
   closed

Hello3
   program
   2016-10-12 13:00
   2016-10-12 15:30
   clay
   test2
   open
```

i.e. I'd like to group the info with the same hostname.
How could I do?

Comment: if `$row['hostname']` != `previous hostname` - output `$row['hostname']`

Comment: @Twinfriends Glad to be of service

Answer (score 4):

If you remember the last `hostname` that you processed, you can test it against the current one and only if they are different output the `hostname` line

```
$query_man = query
$output_man = mysql_query($query_man);

if(mysql_num_rows($output_man) > 0){
    $last_host = NULL;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($output_manutenzione)){

        if ($row['hostname'] != $last_host ) {
            echo "\t" . $row['hostname'];
            $last_host = $row['hostname'];
        }

        echo "\n\t\tTipo Manutenzione: " . $row['type'];
        echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . $row['startdate'];
        echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . $row['enddate'];
        echo "\n\t\tUtente: " . $row['user'];
        echo "\n\t\tMotivo: " . $row['desc'];
        echo "\n\t\tStato: " . $row['State'] . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

This does assume that the query is sorted on `hostname` but your example output is sorted that way so I assume you already did that

> But I have to add this
>
> Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Should also add that the query will need to be sorted by `hostname` if this is going to work.

Comment: @naomik Yup I was just thinking I should add that, thanks for the nudge

Comment: Your answer would have been even better if you yourself had used PDO in the code provided, but I still upvoted. :p

Comment: @ChristianF Yes I agree, but as it is unlikely that a jump from `mysql_` to `PDO` will be undertaken by the OP I deemed it a waste of my time and SO's disk space.

Comment: I'm a big proponent of dragging them, kicking and screaming if need be, into the present. Better to get it over with as soon as possible, before bad habits are established. ;) Anyway, just a minor nit-pick. As I said, your answer is just fine the way it is. You've covered everything relevant, and in a good manner.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the **previous** `hostname` like so:

```
$prev_hostname = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($output_manutenzione)){
    if ($prev_hostname !== $row['hostname']) 
        echo "\t" . $row['hostname'];

    echo "\n\t\tTipo Manutenzione: " . $row['type'];
    echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . $row['startdate'];
    echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . $row['enddate'];
    echo "\n\t\tUtente: " . $row['user'];
    echo "\n\t\tMotivo: " . $row['desc'];
    echo "\n\t\tStato: " . $row['State'] . "\n\n";

    $prev_hostname = $row['hostname'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Memorize `$row['hostname']` value and check if it is the same as previous line. If not, echo the value:

```
$query_man = query
$output_man = mysql_query($query_man);

if(mysql_num_rows($output_man) > 0){

    $prevHostname = '' ;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($output_manutenzione)){
        if ($prevHostname != $row['hostname']) {
            echo "\t" . $row['hostname'];
            $prevHostname = $row['hostname'];
        }
        echo "\n\t\tTipo Manutenzione: " . $row['type'];
        echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . $row['startdate'];
        echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . $row['enddate'];
        echo "\n\t\tUtente: " . $row['user'];
        echo "\n\t\tMotivo: " . $row['desc'];
        echo "\n\t\tStato: " . $row['State'] . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. you need to make some change in code as below with taking one another array

```
<?php $query_man = query
$output_man = mysql_query($query_man);

$array_result = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($output_man) > 0){

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($output_manutenzione)){

    echo "\t" . $row['hostname'];
    echo "\n\t\tTipo Manutenzione: " . $row['type'];
    echo "\n\t\tData inizio: " . $row['startdate'];
    echo "\n\t\tData fine: " . $row['enddate'];
    echo "\n\t\tUtente: " . $row['user'];
    echo "\n\t\tMotivo: " . $row['desc'];
    echo "\n\t\tStato: " . $row['State'] . "\n\n";
    $array_result[$row['hostname']][] = $row;
}
print_r($array_result) ?>
```